DateTimeFormatter abbrevation
DateTime Formatter shows (GMT-8:00) instead of PST
Date date = new Date(2024,11,23);
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("US/Pacific");
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss XXX zzz");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of(zone.toString()));
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(formatter1));

I was expecting : PST or PDT in timezone abbrevation . But coming as (GMT-08:00)
I know the Date(year , month , date) constructor is deprecated. Just trying out with simple constructor. My actual concern is about DateTimeFormatter.

I assume the Date [class], in the first line of the code in your question, is actually class java.util.Date. If it is, then why are you using it? If you initially have a date with no time zone, then why not use LocalDate? By the way, the Date constructor you are using is deprecated. Refer to the documentation.

When I run your code, I get both: 3924/12/22 03:00:00 -08:00 PST. Meaning I cannot reproduce exactly.

You are not getting the date that you intend, but that’s the fault of the outdated Date class and its 25 years long deprecated constructor. Just don’t use that class. More relevant today, beware of the case of format pattern letters. Did you intend lower case hh or upper case HH? Converting your ZoneId to a String and back to a ZoneId seems to be noting but a waste.

If I got your intention right, I would do LocalDate .of(2024, Month.NOVEMBER, 23) .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US))). It returns 2024/11/23 00:00:00 PST. Adjust the details to your needs. And do extract the ZoneId and the formatter into variables or constants as you did in your own code.

actually you should not be using the Date class at all, outdated by the classes from java.time more than 10 years ago... for example new Date(2024, 11, 23) represents December 23th of 3924 (1900+2024, 11+1, 23) which is NOT expected (despite documented), is it?

Sorry for confusion, I know Date(year , month , date) is deprecated . Just trying out with simple constructor. My actual concern is about DateTimeFormatter.

Please give the full expected output string and the full observed output string, not only the chars you were confused about. Or better yet, use a DateTimeFormatter that produces only the output relevant for the question, for example DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz"). Also which Java version are you running? And which is your default locale? Voting to close as not reproducible, but will vote to reopen once you provide a [mre] with the information I mentioned.

Locale
That's due to a missing Locale in the definition of the DateTimeFormatter. Such a Locale defines the language standard for textual representations.
If you don't define the Locale to be used, the DateTimeFormatter will rely on the default one of your JVM.
The following code prints 2024/11/23 12:00:00 -08:00 PST:
// use a local date instead of a date
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2024,11,23);
// use a more specific zone id
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
// use uuuu instead of yyyy and apply a Locale
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "uuuu/MM/dd hh:mm:ss XXX zzz",
         Locale.ENGLISH
);
// then take the beginning of the day in the zone
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = date.atStartOfDay(zone);
// and print the result
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(formatter1));

It is also possible to use a single z instead of 4 or use a v plus Locale.ENGLISH, but a v will only print PT instead of PST.

zzz too works for printing either PST or PDT. Upper case HH would give you hour 00 in the output, which is probably desired. Fine answer with very many good details (+1).

OK, I admit, it's just the missing Locale… However, one should always have a look at the JavaDocs where the pattern letters are explained in a separate section. Edited the answer accordingly…

By the way, some wise folks recommend ignoring the Locale constants like ENGLISH. Instead, use the static factory method Locale.of in Java 19+.  For example: Locale.of( "en" , "US" ) for English language with United States cultural norms.

@BasilBourque Thanks for the link. Because so few premade locales exist, you should probably just avoid these static objects altogether. ... Although these shortcut identifiers are convenient, your code will be more consistent without them.
